# Asp.net mvc entity framework code first associate foreign key with different name

Tags: entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.1, foreign-keys

How can I associate a foreign key with different names here: *createdby* in post and *UserID* in users table.

```
public class Post : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    public long PostID { get; set; }

    public long? ParentPostID { get; set; }      


    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]  
    public virtual User Users { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public long? CreatedBy { get; set; }     
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public long UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mapping is correct - especially the `[ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]` attribute, you don't need to change anything.

In a foreign key relationship in Entity Framework the dependent (= `Post`) and its foreign key always refers to the primary key of the principal (= `User`) - and the primary key is `UserID` - by convention and also because you have marked it with the `Key` attribute. There is nothing you need to specify anymore.

Your relationship is optional (0..1-to-many) because the foreign key `CreatedBy` is nullable (`long?`). So there can be posts in the database which haven't been created by any user. If you don't want this, you can make the relationship required by using a non-nullable foreign key property (`long CreatedBy`).